# How to use a record type variable in plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, function, variables, plpgsql, table-variable

How can I use query result stored into a record type variable for another query within the same stored function? I use Postgres 9.4.4.

With a table like this:

```
create table test (id int, tags text[]);
insert into test values (1,'{a,b,c}'),
                        (2,'{c,d,e}');
```

I wrote a function (simplified) like below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func(_tbl regclass)
RETURNS TABLE (t TEXT[], e TEXT[])
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
  t RECORD;
  c INT;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('SELECT id, tags FROM %s', _tbl) INTO t;
  SELECT count(*) FROM t INTO c;
  RAISE NOTICE '% results', c;
  SELECT * FROM t;
END
$$;
```

... but didn't work:

```
select func('test');
```

> ```
> ERROR:  42P01: relation "t" does not exist
> LINE 1: SELECT count(*) FROM t
>                              ^
> QUERY:  SELECT count(*) FROM t
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function func(regclass) line 7 at SQL statement
> LOCATION:  parserOpenTable, parse_relation.c:986
> ```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The core misunderstanding: a `record` variable holds a *single* row (or is NULL), not a table (0-n rows of a well-known type). There are **no "table variables" in Postgres or PL/pgSQL**. Depending on the task, there are various alternatives:

- [PostgreSQL table variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785767/postgresql-table-variable/10790059#10790059)
- [SELECT multiple rows and columns into a record variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949266/select-multiple-rows-and-columns-into-a-record-variable/24964374#24964374)

Accordingly, you cannot assign ***multiple*** rows to a `record` type variable. In this statement:

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT id, tags FROM %s', _tbl) INTO t;
```

... Postgres assigns *only the first row* and discards the rest. Since "the first" is not well defined in your query, you end up with an arbitrary pick. Obviously due to the misunderstanding mentioned at the outset.

A `record` variable also cannot be used in place of tables in SQL queries. That's the primary cause of the error you get:

> relation "t" does not exist

It should be clear by now, that `count(*)` wouldn't make any sense to begin with, since `t` is just a single record / row - besides being impossible anyway.

Finally (even if the rest would work), your return type seems wrong: <strike>`(t TEXT[], e TEXT[])`</strike>. Since you select `id, tags` into `t`, you'd want to return something like `(id int, e TEXT[])`.

What you are trying to do **would work like this**:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func(_tbl regclass)
  RETURNS TABLE (id int, e text[])
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _ct int;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format(
      'CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp ON COMMIT DROP AS
       SELECT id, tags FROM %s'
    , _tbl);

   GET DIAGNOSTICS _ct = ROW_COUNT;  -- cheaper than another count(*)

   -- ANALYZE tmp;  -- if tmp is big and/or you are going to run many queries

   RAISE NOTICE '% results', _ct;

   RETURN QUERY
   TABLE tmp;  -- shorthand for "SELECT * FROM tmp"
END
$func$;
```

Call **(note the syntax!)**:

```
SELECT * FROM func('test');
```

Related:

- [Postgres creating a local temp table (on commit drop) from a dynamic sql string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217782/postgres-creating-a-local-temp-table-on-commit-drop-from-a-dynamic-sql-string/12218381#12218381)

Just a proof of concept. While you are selecting the whole table, you would just use the underlying table instead. In reality you'll have some `WHERE` clause in the query ...

Careful of the lurking type mismatch, `count()` returns `bigint`, you couldn't assign that to an `integer` variable. Would need a cast: `count(*)::int`.

But I replaced the count completely. It's cheaper to run `GET DIAGNOSTICS` right after `EXECUTE`. [Details in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS)

Why `ANALYZE`?

- [Are regular VACUUM ANALYZE still recommended under 9.1?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/18694/3684)

Aside: CTEs can often do the job in plain SQL:

- [Switching from FOR loops in plpgsql to set-based SQL commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978046/switching-from-for-loops-in-plpgsql-to-set-based-sql-commands/21999333#21999333)

Comment: Thank you so much, Erwin, for kind and detailed answer.  Now the reason is very clear to me.  I will use CTE for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few ways i have used RECORD type variable in plpgsql in redshift database

1. running a loop
2. storing a record variable

Code type 1

```
    $body$
    declare 
    
    arow record ;
    
    begin 
    for arow in ({table})    -- use of record type
      loop
      update #some_table 
        
       column1_some_table := arow.column1,
       column2_some_table := arow.column2 
       where some_condition
      
      end loop ; 
   end ;
   $body$;
```

Code type 2

```
    $body$
    declare 
    
    arow record ;
    counter int := 0;
    max_counter int := 0;
    begin 
    while (counter <= max_counter)
    loop
    select column1, column2 into arow   -- use of record type
      from {table}
      update #some_table 
        
       column1_some_table := arow.column1,
       column2_some_table := arow.column2 
       where some_condition
      counter = counter+1
      end loop ; 
   end ;
   $body$;
```